# Search results won't filter properly [jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi small disclaimer: I have learning disability, sorry in advance.

I have to do a jquery assignment where we make products and then the option to filter them through checkboxes. Now I followed everything we learned in the lesson and tried to apply it but it refuses to filter...

```js
$('.fruit').hide();
$('#fruitCheck').click(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('.fruit').show();
   } else {
       $('.fruit').hide()
   }
};
```

```css
ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
}
div ul li
{
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
}    
img
{
    
}
.fruit p
{
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -15px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 background-color: green;
 font-size:10px;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.frisdrank p
{ 
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -15px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 background-color: red;
 font-size:10px;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}

.dier p
{   
 float: left;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: -15px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 background-color: yellow;
 font-size:10px;
 padding-left:20px;
 padding-right:20px;
 opacity: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<label for="fruitCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" id="fruitcheck"  />
    Fruit
</label>

<div class="row">
    <ul>
        <li class="frisdrank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/FW5hGnb.png" /><p>Cola</p></li>
        <li class="frisdrank"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/N3U2j5t.png" /><p>Fanta</p></li>
        <li class="fruit"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/7yazXfi.png"/><p> Appel</p></li>
        <li class="fruit"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/R4bx4kT.png" /><p>Peer</p></li>
        <li class="dier"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/JshZluf.png" /><p>Hond</p></li>
        <li class="dier"><img src="https://i.imgur.com/00auPwp.png" /><p>Kat</p></li>

    </ul>
</div>


<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="hello_world.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Right now it looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYd89.png

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/97nd3t81/

PS. I know there's only 1 checkbox now, I was planning on just copy pasting them after I had the first one working.

Comment: But where is `fruitCheck`element and `checkbox`  in your code ?

Comment: @SudhirOjha thank you for noticing, i didn't see it wasn't there, how stronge i copied the entire doc.

Comment: create a jsfiddle for the same

Comment: `fruitCheck` and `fruitcheck` are not the same. `<lable>` should come before or after `<input>`, and only contain text too.

Comment: thanks for the answers. added jfiddle and tried what you said @StackSlave but still no luck so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated your JSfiddle, check it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rprakash_19/nuk0jx5r/1/).

```
$('.fruit').hide();
$('#fruitcheck').click(function() {
   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('.fruit').show();
   } else {
       $('.fruit').hide()
   }
});
```

Only missing thing was a parenthesis at the end of the `.click` function. You can find the .click function documentation [here](https://api.jquery.com/click/).

Comment: Thanks a bunch!! Will see what the error was and learn from it. Was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<label for="fruitCheck">
    <input type="checkbox" id="fruitcheck"  />
    Fruit
</label>
```

to

```
<input id='fruitcheck' type='checkbox' /><lable for='fruitcheck'>Fruit</label>
```

Then you can do:

```
var fruits = $('.fruit'), fruitcheck = $('#fruitcheck'); 
fruitcheck.prop('checked', false); fruit.hide();
fruitcheck.click(function(){​
  if(fruitcheck.is(':checked')) {​
    fruits.show();
  } 
  else{​
    fruits.hide();
  }
});
```